# how to match obj with class name with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

in this case I will describe the div as a box that has a hole with a square and round shape.

Box :

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Then, I have an object to put in a box.

Object Shape :

```
var string = [ 
    {shape: 'square', item: 'item1'},
    {shape: 'square', item: 'item2'},
    {shape: 'circle', item: 'item3'}
];
```

then I want to put the object into the box according to the shape of the same hole.

```
$.each(string, function(key, e) {
  /* if inside the div box has several names equal to the value obj */
  if ($('#box').find().attr('class') == e.shape) {

    var data = "<span>" + e.item + "</span>"
    $(data).appendTo(e.shape);

    /* append value item to 
    each div with same name */
  }
});
```

but this code didn't work for me.
the result i want is like this

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="square">
   <span>item1</span>
   <span>item2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <span>item3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var string = [{
      shape: 'square',
      item: 'item1'
    },
    {
      shape: 'square',
      item: 'item2'
    },
    {
      shape: 'circle',
      item: 'item3'
    }
  ];

  $.each(string, function(i, s) {
    $("#box ." + s.shape).append("<span class='item'>" + s.item + "</span>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

This uses the Class selector to select the Shape: `$("." + s.shape)`.  This concatenates the string, so you end up with `$(".square")` for example. Once you have selected the proper element, you can append to it.

**Resulting HTML**

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="square">
    <span class="item">item1</span>
    <span class="item">item2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <span class="item">item3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be dome a bit more simply perhaps by using the shape as a class:

```js
var newContent = [{
    shape: 'square',
    item: 'item1'
  },
  {
    shape: 'square',
    item: 'item2'
  },
  {
    shape: 'circle',
    item: 'item3'
  }
];

$.each(newContent, function(index, val) {
  console.log(index, val);
  $('#box')
    .find("." + val.shape)
    .append("<span class='item-thing'>" + val.item + "</span>")
});
```

```css
.item-thing {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```